# Python/Twisted-- Render Paramiko SFTPFile as if it were twisted.web.static.File

Tags: python, http, twisted

Before I pose the question, some background: I'm creating a web management tool that, among other things, allows the user to download, tail, email, and move and files between predefined directories via the management panel. Many of these directories are local to the server, but some are actually located on remote hosts and accessed via SSH--however, this is transparent to the user. I've used Twisted to create a pseudo-REST API for the client to access, but since I want to avoid revealing actual server paths to the client, it requests downloads of files using a POST with an arbitrary ID to the api, as such: `"http://XXXX:8880/api/transfer/download"`
with POST params similar to this: `{"srckey":"5","srcfile":"solar2-windows-1.10.zip"}`. The idea being the client only knows the key of the directory and filename.

Pardon the excessive background--I'm hoping it will make my question more clear: The issue I have is I'm trying to allow users to download a copy of a file from one of the "remote" hosts via the management server that hosts the web panel, all without caching the file locally. I've used Twisted's File() object to stream large static files before, but since the file resides on another server, I'm trying to accomplish the same using a file object provided by Paramiko's "open()" method.

I've tried setting up a consumer/producer system similar to that used in the render methods of twisted.web.static.File, plugging in the file pointer provided by Paramiko in the appropriate places, but only the smallest text files transfer successfully--all cases cause Paramiko to throw this error:
`socket.error: Socket is closed`

The contents of the relevant python files are here:

- serve-project.py: http://pastebin.com/YcjsQHu3
- WrapSSH.py:
  http://pastebin.com/XaKXJwxb

In a nutshell, I'm trying to stream the data from a Paramiko SFTPFile to an HTTP client. I suspect that my approach is majorly faulty, due to my minimal familiarity with Twisted. Anyone have suggestions on a more intelligent way to accomplish this?

Comment: I apologize in advance for the code--this is a prototype and needs refactored badly.

Comment: Since posting this, I have actually changed my project so that communication is done using WAMP via Crossbar.io and Autobahn. Answers to this question would still be very useful, but I'm also having the same issue with my new system (How do I transfer a binary file over an existing WAMP connection.) I have an idea for that, and may close this if I figure that out.

Comment: Sorry to say, there's far too much extraneous code in your example and I'm not quite sure what you're trying to ask here.  Paramiko is a blocking SSH client, so it isn't going to integrate with Twisted super well; you probably want Conch or just spawnProcess over OpenSSH.  If you could clean this up into a self-contained example with a simpler explanation of the problem statement it would be a lot easier to answer.